# Magento 2 Klarna payment title change not working

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, klarna

In checkout page Klarna payment title not changing. It is fetching title from checkout config and can't find where to set it.
Below is the image
[image]

Need to change it,only 'Klarna Pay'

Thanks in advance.